# Will a 3rd party SFP module void Cisco warranty?

Tags: cisco, sfp

Will using a non-Cisco branded SFP module void any warranty with Cisco (either with the switch or network module)?

The SFP we are looking for more cost effective alternatives is SFP-10G-SR-S in a C9300-NM-8X.

Comment: It may not void the warranty, but TAC may insist on replacing it before they continue troubleshooting with you.

Comment: Also removed off-topic request for opinions.

Comment: There are loads of non-Cisco branded transceivers available, and some have been certified to work with Cisco equipment while others have not. The ones that have been certified should not be an issue with TAC but using a non-Certified transceiver may either not work at all or you may need to enable the option allowing you to use unsupported transceivers (in which case TAC is likely going to insist on replacing it before working on a case with you).  I have some Proline transceivers, which are certified compatible, in some C9300 switches I manage, and never had an issue with TAC, for example.

Comment: Where "certified" means it has an acceptable signature, not that anyone actually tested/approved them. There are many companies that will put whatever vendor signature you want on it. (Cisco's happens to be publicly known.)

Answer (score 1):

Generally third party optics will not void Cisco's warranty but are also considered unsupported.  In practice this means that if TAC sees an issue potentially associated with a third party optic in the box that they may ask you to swap in an actual Cisco part in the interest of troubleshooting.  If the underlying issue has nothing to do with optics in the box then it's a non-issue.

One notable exception are optics modules that don't have a direct equivalent in the Cisco catalog.  As an example I'd be *really* cautious with 10GBaseT SFP's, as the earlier generations (...which Cisco and most of its competitors refused to sell) could draw enough power to either damage supply circuitry or cause significant thermal problems.  Similarly extra long-distance fiber modules that draw excessive power could cause failures.  I'd imagine the failure mode would have to be something pretty egregious (i.e. something burning down) before there would be a question.